# Apache Rewrite rule to manage language redirections

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to structure a rewrite rule to implement redirection based on languages.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── .htaccess
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   └── master.min.css
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff
│   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff2
│   │   └── FontAwesome.otf
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── logo.svg
│   │   ├── slide1.jpg
│   │   ├── slide2.jpg
│   │   ├── slide3.jpg
│   │   └── slide4.jpg
│   └── js
│       └── scripts.min.css
├── de
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── sie.php
│   ├── uns.php
│   └── zusammen.php
├── en
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── together.php
│   ├── us.php
│   └── you.php
├── fr
│   ├── ensemble.php
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── nous.php
│   └── vous.php
└── it
    ├── index.php
    ├── insieme.php
    ├── noi.php
    └── voi.php
```

I have no root index.html or index.php file. I want to have the .htaccess redirect the user to one of the index files inside the language directories by sniffing the browser language and then redirecting the user to the appropriate language. The default language, when the browser's language cannot be sniffed should be French.

My current .htaccess file consists of the following:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|it)/ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fr/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/$1 [L]
```

This seem to function partially, but it isn't able to access the various assets such as images, javascripts, or fonts.

Once the page loads, thereafter, there shouldn't be any problems navigating and changing languages as I have used internal URLs that are directly linking to the specific pages in the appropriate directories.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect and route using browser's languages. Place this code in root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(assets|en|de|fr|it)/ - [L,NC]

# detect browser language and capture first 2 chars
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2}) [NC]
# current request is not pointing to a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# check if corresponding directory exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/ -d
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

## default fr rule
# current request is not pointing to a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# current request is not pointing to a real directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/?$ fr%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: I was updating my question as you were writing your reply. I got it somewhat solved, but I am having problems accessing the assets as my updated question indicates. Can you please update your answer with my changes indicated above in mind please?

Comment: I tried your solution and got a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: No difference...still get an internal server error.

Comment: If you're around...I need another bit of help with that. Once the index has been loaded, if I navigate to another language via the links that change the language, images and other assets no longer work because from then on, rather than looking for `/assets/img` or `/assets/js` it prepends the language code and tries to load the assets from `/en/assets/img` or `/en/assets/js`. Is there a way to address this? Maybe I should move this discussion into a chat

Comment: That is most likely due to your use of relative links for css/js/images. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: OK, that solved it, but I'm a bit surprised because I'm not using relative links, well, not fully relative...for example `<script src="/assets/js/main.min.js"></script>` That should be from site root, unless there's a better syntax.

Comment: Glad it solved it but I am surprised too as `/assets/js/main.min.js` is NOT a relative link but the fact that `<base href` solved it I guess somehow browser is getting relative link.

Comment: OK, somehow, it won't let me move this to a chat. It's very strange. The only thing I can think of is that somehow, the rewrite-rule is relativising the URLs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you try include assets in you source code, So you can try make this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(img|css|js|fonts)/(.*)$ assets/$2/$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(fr|it|en|de)/(.*)$ $2/index.php?area=$3   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
```

Comment: Is your updated answer in relation to the changes I made to my question?

Comment: No, my answer is for the first variant.

Comment: Can you perhaps update to reflect the progress I made in resolving the issue, or let me know if there is a benefit to using your method and if so, will I need to accommodate the same problems I am having with assets?

Comment: I tried your solution and I got the following error: `You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected. You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.`

Comment: So, now you can try to place my example into your .htaccess file in the root directory of your page.

Comment: I am still getting the permission issue. However, my current .htaccess file (above) does work without any problems except the loading of assets which are in the `/assets/*` hierarchy.

Comment: That only include this line in your file: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(img|css|js|fonts)/(.*)$ assets/$2/$3 [QSA,L]`